# If I put a try statement in a for loop, where does the catch go using swift 5.1

Tags: swift

I am trying to see if an SQLite.swift database is setup by selecting the last row, and if it's not setup, I will reload the database table from a file.
But I'm using code based on the SQLite.swift documentation, which doesn't provide enough context in the far too brief example code.

```
let query = Bible.select(id, Book, Chapter, Verse, KJV)
            .filter(id == 31102)

        for verse in try! db.prepare(query) {
            print("The Bible is in the DB.\n")
            DataLoaded = true
        } catch {
            DataLoaded = false
        }
```

I understand the '!' after try suppresses the error, so the catch I've put at the end is doing nothing, but if I remove the '!' an error message says "Errors from here are not handled".
If I take away the '!', where should I put the catch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop is irrelevant. The `catch` needs to be paired with a `do`.

```
do {
    // anything involving a try
} catch {
}
```

So your code should be more like this:

```
do {
    for verse in try db.prepare(query) {
        print("The Bible is in the DB.\n")
    } 
    DataLoaded = true // Put this inside the loop if loading any data, and not all, is considered success
} catch {
    DataLoaded = false
}
```

And don't use `try!` with `catch`. Just use `try`.